# How to add and remove tabs from/to My Account page

Tags: views

I have created a role **Customers**. I added **UserA** to the role. When I logged in as UserA, I see **My Account** link in the Header region. After I click **My Account**, I see three tabs : Views, Edit, Checklists. How to remove Edit and Checklists tabs from the **My Account** page?

I created a page view. The path for the page view is xxx.com/payments. How can I add a new tab (Payment) next to **Views** tab on the **My Account** page? When UserA clicks the **Payment** tab, the page view xxx.com/payments displays right under all the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question answer remove the  from page.tpl.php or you can alter it by hook_menu_alter. Use type MENU_NORMAL_ITEM.

For you view you need to create one hook_menu_alter and add type as MENU_LOCAL_TASK.